# Using two identical dependencies with different versions mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, hikaricp

My application needs to connect to two different databases, the first database version is 5, the second database version is 8. Question: how do I register maven dependencies and how do I use hikaricp correctly?

my pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql.</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.49</version>
</dependency>
```

after that I see that maven has downloaded two versions of the drivers.

Hibernate SessionFactory

```java
protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory( List<Class> classes ) {
    StandardServiceRegistry        registry        = null;
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();

    try {
        registry = registryBuilder.applySettings( this.buildSettings() ).build();
        MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources( registry );
        for ( Class aClass : classes ) {
            metadataSources.addAnnotatedClass( aClass );
        }
        Metadata metadata = metadataSources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
        return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        if ( registry != null ) StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
        System.err.println( "Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + e );
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError( e );
    }
}
private Map<String, Object> buildSettings() {
    Map<String, Object> settings = new HashMap<>();
    settings.put( Environment.DRIVER, dbModel.getDriver() );
    settings.put( Environment.DIALECT, dbModel.getDialect() );
    settings.put( Environment.URL, dbModel.getUrl() );
    settings.put( Environment.USER, dbModel.getUser() );
    settings.put( Environment.PASS, dbModel.getSecret() );
    settings.put( Environment.SHOW_SQL, dbModel.getShowSql() );
    settings.put( Environment.ENABLE_LAZY_LOAD_NO_TRANS, dbModel.getLazyLoad() );

    settings.put( "hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout", dbModel.getConnectionTimeout() );
    settings.put( "hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout", dbModel.getIdleTimeout() );
    settings.put( "hibernate.hikari.maxLifetime", dbModel.getMaxLifetime() );
    settings.put( "hibernate.hikari.autoCommit", dbModel.getAutoCommit() );
    settings.put( "hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle", dbModel.getMinimumIdle() );
    settings.put( "hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize", dbModel.getMaxPoolSize() );
    settings.put( "hibernate.hikari.registerMbeans", dbModel.getRegisterMbean() );

    return settings;
}
```

when debugging, I see that the variable hibernate.connection.driver_class is set to com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
[image]

but when building I see an error
[image: error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is probably a typo: `<groupId>mysql.</groupId>` (the dot at the end of mysql).

Comment: No Fabian, this is not a typo. If the mysql dependency is specified without a dot in the pom file, then version 5 of the mysql driver is loaded, or the one specified last in the pom file. and I do not claim that this solution `<groupId>mysql.</groupId>` is correct, I just found this solution somewhere on the Internet.

Comment: You mean you changed the groupId of the artifact from `mysql` to `mysql.` ? From the Maven side, this allows you to load both, but don't they still overlap in classes? I mean, if both version 5 and 8 have classes with the same qualified name, then loading both will usually lead to trouble.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then MySQL version 5 has the class name = `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, and mysql version 8 has the class name = `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. When I build `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`, I add the string `Environment.DRIVER = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to HashMap ().

Comment: The classes you mentioned have different qualified names, but there might be others that share a name. Generally, it is not a good idea to try to load both dependencies in the same program.

Comment: How can I use two drivers of different versions in the same program?

Comment: Can the `mysql-connector-java` in version `8.x` not also connect to a database of a lower version?

Comment: No, with the driver version 8, I can't connect to older versions of mysql(exactly mysql version 5.1). when connecting, I get the client_plugin_auth error.

Comment: I would have a look at the maven shade plugin which allows you to relocate dependencies.